# Animating a translation works one way but not the other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When animating the "bar" up and above the "banner," it seems to work well (though I would prefer the banner to be in front). However, the main issue comes when I try to animate the bar back down to its initial position, but the animation ceases to exist. It simply teleports downward and does not translate down as the object had translated upward nicely before.

Why is that and how can I fix this problem? Thanks!

```js
var active = false;

$("#banner").click(function() {
  if (active) {
    // show the bar and then "animate" it downward
    $("#bar").show().animate({
      translate: 0
    }, {
      duration: 500,
      step: function(pix) {
        $("#bar").css("transform", "translateY(" + pix + "px)");
      }
    });
  } else {
    // "animate" bar upward and hide it
    $("#bar").animate({
      translate: -1000
    }, {
      duration: 500,
      step: function(pix) {
        $("#bar").css("transform", "translateY(" + pix + "px)");
      },
      done: function() {
        $("#bar").hide();
      }
    });
  }
  active = !active;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#banner {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#bar {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 0;
}

#bar p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner">
  <p>Title</p>
</div>
<div id="bar">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Clarification: clicking the banner begins the animation. The first works; the second doesn't.

Comment: There is no animation running in your snippet code

Comment: @AnmolJuneja The animations are triggered by clicking the banner. The first animation works, but the second doesn't.

Comment: have you checked the code?

Answer (score 0):

So it's very easy just add (below property) to #bar

```
transition: .5s transform ease;
```

Do let me know it's work for you not

Comment: That works, but why does the jQuery animation not work? It makes no sense for it to animate perfectly upward but not downward.